# Moving from Office365 Auth to OAuth

Tags: oauth, office365, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

So there's a piece of software using the deprecated Office365 Auth type and I am working to change it. However I cannot seem to get my head around how to edit the following:

```
            String _fetchxml = getFetch();
         using (CrmServiceClient crmConn = new CrmServiceClient(ConnectionString)
         {
             _crmService = crmConn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
             EntityCollection tn = _crmService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(_fetchxml));
```

This used to work via Office365, but now just throws an Object Reference error.

Could anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CrmServiceClient` implements `IOrganizationService`, so you can skip the `OrganizationServiceProxy` and directly use `crmConn` :

`var tn = crmConn.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(_fetchxml));`

Beyond that, maybe check the version of the `Xrm.Tooling` NuGet package you're using. If it's not the latest, you might want to update.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! The package I had was out of date :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear you're back in business.